# Limit API request at a user level

Tags: api, limits

I wondering if it's possible to control the 24hr API request limit at the user level.

For example, if I have a 100k 24hr limit, I may want to prevent a specific integration user from consuming more than 50k of those.

Is this possible?

Comment: if the API requests are coming into apex rest classes or otherwise execute some known set of triggers/PB+flows, then you could count by user and send alerts to the submitting system to say "knock it off, you've done enough for the day" but that won't actually put any hard stop on new requests

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No.** You cannot control API usage at User level, it's always aggregated at the Org level irrespective of a User.

You can find the reference for this on [System Overview: API Usage](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dev_force_com_system_overview_api.htm&type=5) documentation (emphasis mine):

> Limits are enforced against the aggregate of all API calls made by the org in a 24 hour period. **Limits are not on a per-user basis**. When an org exceeds a limit, all users in the org can be temporarily blocked from making additional calls. Calls are blocked until usage for the preceding 24 hours drops below the limit.